# log4j is creating log with manual.log, manual.log.1 so on

Tags: log4j

My log4j properties as follows,

```
#Application Logger
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,file
#log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,file,console
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=../common/logs/api/log4j-app.log

log4j.appender.file.maxFileSize=6MB
log4j.appender.file.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c<strong><strong>{1}</strong></strong>:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p : %L --  %m%n
log4j.appender.file.Append=false


#Manual WebLogs
log4j.logger.webLogger=INFO, web
log4j.appender.web=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.web.maxFileSize=900KB
log4j.appender.web.maxBackupIndex=6
log4j.appender.web.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.web.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p %F <Method>%M : %L --  %m%n
log4j.appender.web.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p : %L --  %m%n
log4j.appender.web.File=../common/logs/web/manual.log
log4j.appender.web.Append=false

#Manual ApiLogs
log4j.logger.apiLogger=INFO, api ,console
log4j.appender.api=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.api.maxFileSize=900KB
log4j.appender.api.maxBackupIndex=6
log4j.appender.api.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.api.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p %F <Method>%M : %L --  %m%n
log4j.appender.api.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p : %L --  %m%n
log4j.appender.api.File=../common/logs/api/manual.log
log4j.appender.api.Append=false

#Manual ApiSecurityLogs
log4j.logger.apiSecurityLogger=INFO, apiSecurity
log4j.appender.apiSecurity=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.apiSecurity.maxFileSize=900KB
log4j.appender.apiSecurity.maxBackupIndex=6
log4j.appender.apiSecurity.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.apiSecurity.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p %F <Method>%M : %L --  %m%n
log4j.appender.apiSecurity.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601}  : %L --  %m%n
log4j.appender.apiSecurity.File=../common/logs/apiSecurity/manualSecurity.log
log4j.appender.apiSecurity.Append=false

# Appender which writes to console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c %m%n
```

We are using the above log4j.properties to create web logs and api logs.

web related logs goes to `web/manual.log`.
api related logs goes to `api/manual.log`.
api security related logs goes to `apiSecurity/manualSecurity.log`

for api  `manual.log` and `log4j-app.log` files are creating as
`manual.log, manual.log.1, manual.log.2` ...etc.,
`log4j-app.log, log4j-app.log.1, log4j-app.log.2` ... so on.

I want all the log details in a single file as `manual.log` and `log4j-app.log`, please let me know how to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appenders type needs to be changed from RollingFileAppender to **FileAppender**. 
So after changing it, your log4j.properties would look like:

```
#Application Logger
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,file
#log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,file,console
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=log4j-app.log

#log4j.appender.file.maxFileSize=6MB
#log4j.appender.file.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c<strong><strong>{1}</strong></strong>:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p : %L --  %m%n
log4j.appender.file.Append=false


#Manual WebLogs
log4j.logger.webLogger=INFO, web
log4j.appender.web=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
#log4j.appender.web.maxFileSize=900KB
#log4j.appender.web.maxBackupIndex=6
log4j.appender.web.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.web.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p %F <Method>%M : %L --  %m%n
log4j.appender.web.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p : %L --  %m%n
log4j.appender.web.File=../common/logs/web/manual.log
log4j.appender.web.Append=false

#Manual ApiLogs
log4j.logger.apiLogger=INFO, api ,console
log4j.appender.api=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
#log4j.appender.api.maxFileSize=900KB
#log4j.appender.api.maxBackupIndex=6
log4j.appender.api.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.api.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p %F <Method>%M : %L --  %m%n
log4j.appender.api.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p : %L --  %m%n
log4j.appender.api.File=manual.log
log4j.appender.api.Append=false

#Manual ApiSecurityLogs
log4j.logger.apiSecurityLogger=INFO, apiSecurity
log4j.appender.apiSecurity=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.apiSecurity.maxFileSize=900KB
log4j.appender.apiSecurity.maxBackupIndex=6
log4j.appender.apiSecurity.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.apiSecurity.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p %F <Method>%M : %L --  %m%n
log4j.appender.apiSecurity.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601}  : %L --  %m%n
log4j.appender.apiSecurity.File=../common/logs/apiSecurity/manualSecurity.log
log4j.appender.apiSecurity.Append=false

# Appender which writes to console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %c %m%n
```

Comment: what is the difference between RollingFileAppender and FileAppender? could you please explain me

Comment: Thanks for your answer